# nodejs imgur api - over capacity 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, imgur

I keep getting this error when trying to use the imgur search api in nodejs:

```
{"data":{"error":"Imgur is temporarily over capacity. Please try again later."},"success":false,"status":500}
```

I dont get this error when accessing the api through a REST client which makes me think I'm doing something wrong. When I use the REST client I get the results I expect. This is how I'm accessing the api in node.

```
var https = require("https");

var options = {
  protocol:"https:",
  host:"api.imgur.com",
  path:"3/gallery/search/top/all/0?q=cats",
  headers:{"Authorization" : "Client-ID ***********"}
}

var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: Did you use the REST client at about the same time as the Node app?

Comment: Yeah definitely. Not sure which one I used first though... I've been fighting this for a day or two as well so I've been trying both on and off.

Comment: I've also tried running this on cloud 9, heroku, and locally with the same error result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `path` in the request `options` is incorrect. Prepend `/` and voila!

Simply change:

```
path:"3/gallery/search/top/all/0?q=cats",
```

to

```
path:"/3/gallery/search/top/all/0?q=cats",
```

The following worked perfectly for me!

```
var https = require("https");

var options = {
  protocol:"https:",
  host:"api.imgur.com",
  path:"/3/gallery/search/top/all/0?q=cats",
  headers:{"Authorization" : "Client-ID {YOUR_ID}"}
}

var req = https.request(options, function(response) {
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(JSON.parse(str));
  });
});

req.end();
```

Comment: This is not the solution. Imgur has a problem for themselves.

Comment: @nakorndev this same code is working for me now just as it did 4 years ago. I'm getting a 200 and an array of results. Perhaps you ran into a separate issue than the original poster did. Feel free to elaborate here. Though, I'm not sure a down vote is necessary if that's the case since it's unrelated.